# What is the spread syntax good for in PHP?

Tags: php, spread-syntax

I use spread syntax in JavaScript, but what are they used for in PHP? In all cases which I've tried it acts just like a usual array. Is there some good use for it which I didn't find?

(I know how it works, just asking for a useful example, where it is more useful than array)

Comment: @zack6849 Found this topic but it didn't fill my expectations. It looks useless.

Comment: It looks to me like whatever a js spread operator is is not equivalent in php, it's a [variable length argument list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: @zack6849 Well in function (...$var) $var comes like a array of arguments. I would still rather use array. Like ([value, value, value])

Comment: i mean, i guess, it's just a feature, nobody is going to force you to sue it a specific way

Comment: I agree, I was just looking for some useful features with it, in JS it looks more useful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spread operator (`...`) transforms an array (or generically a `Traversable`) into an argument list, and vice-versa. If you're looking for anything more fancy than this, you're out of luck: the [Javascript implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is simply more powerful, in that it *also* transforms object expressions into key-value pairs, and vice-versa.

How might you use this? Well, consult the [original RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) that defined it for some practical examples:

- More performant than `call_user_func_array`
- Extending variadic functions: forwarding
- Partial application: multiple unpacks

I personally use it because of that first point. As mentioned in the RFC:

> The ... argument unpacking syntax is about 3.5 to 4 times faster than call_user_func_args. This solves the performance issue. Benchmark code and results.

You might also ask *why* PHP didn't implement the object unpacking, like Javascript. That too is answered in the RFC:

> In order to ensure forward-compatibility with named arguments the unpacking operator does not support string keys. If a string key is encountered during unpacking a recoverable error is thrown. If the error is ignored using a custom error handler, no further arguments will be unpacked but the call still happens.

I *personally* find this to be a trap, which is why I abstained from voting on this RFC.